# UiScrollable not working in UiAutomator

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-uiautomator

I am new to UIautomator and needed to select "Settings" from Apps.
This is the code that demo provide:

```
 package Test;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiScrollable;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiSelector;
import com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase;

public class LaunchSettings extends       UiAutomatorTestCase {
public void testDemo() throws     UiObjectNotFoundException {

getUiDevice().pressHome();

UiObject allAppsButton = new UiObject(new       UiSelector().description("Apps"));

UiObject appsTab = new UiObject(new   UiSelector().text("Apps"));
appsTab.click();

UiScrollable appViews = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true));

              appViews.setAsHorizontalList();

UiObject settingsApp = appViews.getChildByText(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.TextView.class.getName()), "Settings");
settingsApp.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
UiObject settingsValidation = new UiObject(new UiSelector().packageName("com.android.settings"));
assertTrue("Unable to detect Settings",    settingsValidation.exists());
    }
}
```

While executing this it gets into "App" and do nothing, the error code is below:

[Error report image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPY5e.png)

```
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testDemo
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
Test results for WatcherResultPrinter=.E
Time: 19.974

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 0,  Errors: 1
```

Would appreciate if someone could point out what am I doing wrong, this is my 1st time and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what is Line 58?

Comment: its：UiObject settingsApp = appViews.getChildByText(
                new UiSelector().className(android.widget.TextView.class.getName()), "Settings");
        settingsApp.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no scrollable view in "Apps" tab. Therefore, you just launch the setting menu like this.

```
    Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);

    mDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS).depth(0)), 5000);
```